# Biztalk two schemas and loop functoid with condition

Tags: mapping, biztalk

How to create mapping when on input we will have two schema's and on output will be one schema and some condition across mapping ?

Input is an inline schema and contains Invoices and Customers schema's.
Both of them have CustomerNumber and DepartmentCode exist only on Invoices schema.

**[CONDITION]**

*Mapp only this **DepartmentCode** if **CustomerNumber** is same on both Invoice and Customer data (line)*.

```
If Invoice.CustomerNumber == Customer.CustomerNumber then map Invoice.DepartmentCode.
```

I've tried to use [loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559012.aspx), equal and value mapping functoid's but without expected results,
second think I've tried to use "Inline xslt call template" but I've got an error on processing.

**[Code of XSLT functoid]**

```
<xsl:template name="GetDepartmenCodeByCustomerNumber">
    <xsl:param name="CustomerNumber" />
    <xsl:if test="$CustomerNumber != ''">
        <xsl:element name="DepartmentCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="//s1:Customer[s1:CustomerNumber=$CustomerNumber]/s1:DepartmentCode/text()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Example:

**Input**

```
<ROOT>
 <Invoices>
  <Invoice>
   <CustomerNumber>123</CustomerNumber>
   <DepartmentCode>321</DepartmentCode>
  </Invoice>
 </Invoices>
 <Customers>
  <Customer>
   <CustomerNumber>123</CustomerNumber>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
   <CustomerNumber>222</CustomerNumber>
  </Customer>
 </Customers>
</ROOT>
```

**Expect**

```
<Document>
 <CustomerNumber>123</CustomerNumber>
 <DepartmentCode>321</DepartmentCode>
</Document>
```

For example I need to equal CustomerNumber from Invoice and Customer segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a "double" loop because I guess you have multiple Invoices and Customers. A xslt is a good solution, but if you only need these two fields you can use a map like this:

[image]

Loop the invoice to a [Table Looping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559310.aspx) adding its two children and a [Cumulative Concatenate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267873.aspx) of all the CNumb (adding some special character to allow the search later, for example @CNumb@) from Customers. Use the [Table Extractors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559310.aspx) to get all the values and check if each CNumb from Invoices is in the concatenation or not, sending the result of the comparison to the loop element in destination schema.

Comment: Please verify parameters (input/output) for these functoid's.

[Concatenate](http://imgur.com/1qVM3MD),
[Cumulative](http://imgur.com/3NoxIAc).

For this one [TLoop](http://imgur.com/MUUQ1dP) these param's are correct ? and second one I do not need to create table on it ? 

I think I need to add "0" at second param for [Greater](http://imgur.com/ypHxweb), I'm a right ?

[TExtractor](http://imgur.com/8LD1JXL) depends on Table loop func, what I need to set to solve warnings problem (on all of this type) ?

Comment: In TLoop you need to use as second parameter the number of columns that you want, so add "3" as second parameter. Once this is done, you can configure the columns in Table Looping Grid. In Greater yes, you need to add the "0" for the comparison. In the TExtractors you need to add as second parameters the column number. You have 3 columns in the table, so use "1", ",2" and "3" for them according the column that you are getting.

Comment: I had to add Trim left and right before String Find - but it worked!